# ESP32 CAM only Web Server no Streaming

Tags: c, stream, camera, jupyter, arduino-esp32

I connected esp32 cam using CameraWebServerStream in Arduino. I used a static ip address using port forwarding. However, when I enter the web server, the live streaming does not work. (Capture works fine)
When I write code using url address in Jupyter notebook and spyder, stream video comes out. Why can't I stream live only on the web server?

## arduino code

```
#include "esp_camera.h"
#include <WiFi.h>

#define CAMERA_MODEL_AI_THINKER // Has PSRAM

#include "camera_pins.h"

const char* ssid = "/ipname/";
const char* password = "/ipPWD/";

IPAddress staticIP(192, 168, 100, 33); 
IPAddress gateway(192, 168, 100, 1); 

IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0);


void startCameraServer();
 
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  if (WiFi.config(staticIP, gateway, subnet) == false) {
   Serial.println("Configuration failed.");
}

  Serial.setDebugOutput(true);
  Serial.println();

  camera_config_t config;
  config.ledc_channel = LEDC_CHANNEL_0;
  config.ledc_timer = LEDC_TIMER_0;
  config.pin_d0 = Y2_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d1 = Y3_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d2 = Y4_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d3 = Y5_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d4 = Y6_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d5 = Y7_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d6 = Y8_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d7 = Y9_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_xclk = XCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pclk = PCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_vsync = VSYNC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_href = HREF_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_sda = SIOD_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_scl = SIOC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pwdn = PWDN_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_reset = RESET_GPIO_NUM;
  config.xclk_freq_hz = 20000000;
  config.pixel_format = PIXFORMAT_JPEG;
  
  // if PSRAM IC present, init with UXGA resolution and higher JPEG quality
  //                      for larger pre-allocated frame buffer.
  if(psramFound()){
    config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_UXGA;
    config.jpeg_quality = 10;
    config.fb_count = 2;
  } else {
    config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_SVGA;
    config.jpeg_quality = 12;
    config.fb_count = 1;
  }

#if defined(CAMERA_MODEL_ESP_EYE)
  pinMode(13, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(14, INPUT_PULLUP);
#endif

  // camera init
  esp_err_t err = esp_camera_init(&config);
  if (err != ESP_OK) {
    Serial.printf("Camera init failed with error 0x%x", err);
    return;
  }

  sensor_t * s = esp_camera_sensor_get();
  // initial sensors are flipped vertically and colors are a bit saturated
  if (s->id.PID == OV3660_PID) {
    s->set_vflip(s, 1); // flip it back
    s->set_brightness(s, 1); // up the brightness just a bit
    s->set_saturation(s, -2); // lower the saturation
  }
  // drop down frame size for higher initial frame rate
  s->set_framesize(s, FRAMESIZE_QVGA);

#if defined(CAMERA_MODEL_M5STACK_WIDE) || defined(CAMERA_MODEL_M5STACK_ESP32CAM)
  s->set_vflip(s, 1);
  s->set_hmirror(s, 1);
#endif

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");

  startCameraServer();

  Serial.print("Camera Ready! Use 'http://");
  Serial.print(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println("' to connect");
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  delay(10000);
}
```

## jupyter notebook code

If run this code, streaming video comes out well.

```
import cv2
from urllib.request import urlopen
import numpy as np

 #It should be done with capture, not stream, streaming video works normally
url = r'http://192.168.0.46:5702/capture' 
while True:
    img_resp = urlopen(url)
    imgnp = np.asarray(bytearray(img_resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
    img = cv2.imdecode(imgnp, -1)
    cv2.imshow("Camera", img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 113:
        break
```

## web server

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because startCameraServer() starts two servers, one on port 80 for index page, and one on port 81 for the stream itself.

So you need to forward both ports.

Comment: I also face same problem, MR JJung  cold you solve that problem.  ? If yes Then How, kindly tell us.